# How are the joins ordered in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I would to know more about query optimizer in sqlite. For order of join, on the website there are only

> When selecting the order of tables in a join, SQLite uses an efficient
>   polynomial-time algorithm. Because of this, SQLite is able to plan
>   queries with 50- or 60-way joins in a matter of microseconds.

but where are the details, what is the specific function?

Comment: You can read this: [The Next Generation Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html). The next step I guess would be to read the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

The SQLite Query Planner: Joins:
 http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#joins

The Next Generation Query Planner:
http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html